# swanky deploy throws error " ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: ink, smart-contract, astar

I am using [`Swanky Suite`](https://docs.astar.network/docs/wasm/sc-dev/swanky), contract compile successfully but while deploy using `swanky deploy --account alice --contract flipper --gas 100000000 --args true` throws `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open` error. `Swanky node` also run in next tab. Why contract doesn't deploy?

[image]

Comment: looking at the screenshot, you are indeed missing the wasm binary and metadata.json.
If the compile step was completed correctly, those should have been there.
Can you run the compile command again with `--verbose` flag and check the output?

Comment: and please add `ls` printout for `flipper/target/ink` folder

Comment: thanks for comments, I have issue with nodejs version now works fine

Comment: I had the same error, but noted that the previous compile step fails even though it gives green checkmarks: ⠋ Copying artifacts[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/home/justin/dev/chocolate-wasm/artifacts/asset.contract' -> '/home/justin/dev/chocolate-wasm/artifacts/asset/1673627007627/asset.wasm'. What version of nodejs worked for you?

Comment: I am using `@astar-network/swanky-cli/1.0.7-jp-workshop.3 darwin-x64 node-v18.12.1`

Comment: @Ganesh11 Can you mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-posting the answer from the comment here to remove the question from the unanswered section:

The issue was an old version of node.js.